# Copy and append multiple files into a single file

Tags: append, xcopy

I want command line interface, To copy all files in SRC folder and subdirectories ending with names **appl.h** and append the content of all files into a single file **newfile.txt.**

```
xcopy C:\SRC\*appl.h newfile.txt /s
```

But the problem is it does not append the files but **overwrites** the **newfile.txt**